# What does the @Embedded annotation in Morphia actually do?

Tags: java, mongodb, annotations, morphia

When writing documents to `Mongodb` using `Morphia`, a structure like this will be written without any problems, and **without** needing the `@Embedded` annotation:

```
@Entity
public class Blog {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private List<Comment> comments;
}
```

The `comments` field is happily stored as an array of nested `Comment` elements (`Comment` is a plain POJO with no annotations).

However, the `Morphia` documentation suggests I should be using this:

```
@Entity
public class Blog {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Embedded
    private List<Comment> comments;
}
```

But in my tests using the `@Embedded` annotation doesn't appear to do anything additional over simply writing the structure without the annotation.

So what does the `@Embedded` annotation actually do? Does it affect the ability to query, or index, or some other function of storage other than simply writing the data?

Answer (score 5):

`Serializable` is not generally used with Morphia.  `@Embedded` is a bit of an ambiguous item whose original intent seems to have gotten lost.  In fact, in my fork which I'm working on making the official 2.0 of Morphia, I've restricted it such that it only applies at the class level.  This tells Morphia to map the type but not fail the mapping on a missing `@Id` annotation.  In that branch if you wish to specify a name other than the field name, you'd simply use `@Property` as you would for any non-embedded types.

I hope this clarifies it a little bit at least.

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks for your reply. So does it make any difference if I use @Embedded or not? My nested objects aren't marked Serializable either, but it doesn't seem to cause any issues.

Comment: In practice, no.  If you explicitly call map() on that type, I think Morphia will complain at which point you'll want to use use `@Embedded` on it but the on the fly mapping does much less validation in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, you should `@Embedded` for objects that are dependent on the parent object (and therefore have no life outside it), and are not shared between objects.

By default, Morphia uses the field name as the value name in Mongo. This can be overridden by specifying a name on the @Embedded annotation:

```
    @Embedded("blog_comments")
    private List<Comment> comments;
```

Even without `@Embedded` you can still use java class as field type as long as that class implements `java.io.Serializable`. However that field will be stored in MongoDB in binary format instead of structured data as shown above.

Sources [here](https://github.com/jmkgreen/morphia/wiki/Embedded-Annotation) and [here](https://www.playframework.com/modules/morphia-1.2.7/model#embed)